# On linux ubuntu 16 32bit, DrPaulcarter assembly language tutorial, undefined reference error

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm new in assembly language, so i am following Dr.Paul Carter's pcasm tutorial(
http://pacman128.github.io/pcasm/ 
).

Exactly pdf file(http://pacman128.github.io/static/pcasm-book.pdf) page-33, and book's page-23

From that site, i downloaded Linux Example (http://pacman128.github.io/static/linux-ex.zip)

and at the terminal i input

1. `nasm -f coff first.asm`
2. `gcc -c driver.c`
3. `nasm -f coff asm_io.o`
4. `gcc -o first driver.o first.o asm_io.o`

But it returned it

[image]

Where is problem?

(Screenshot's command -lc is no matter, if there is no -lc, it returned the same thing)

Comment: Linux uses ELF (`nasm -f elf32`) not coff, I am surprised that even worked. Also, we don't use leading underscore so remove those. Furthermore `nasm -f coff asm_io.o` should of course be `asm_io.asm` not `.o` (copy paste error?)

Comment: @Jester Thanks asm_io.asm is my fault, I'll try your advise

Comment: Use cut & paste to include the output of the command not a screenshot.

Comment: I think it is time to find another tutorial...

Comment: why are nasm and assembly tags used here?  why is it mostly links and not real content?

Comment: As the text you link to says: "The examples in the text of the tutorial are for DJGPP only". DJGPP is a DOS compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux `asm_io` doesn't work with 64-bit. You have to create 32-bit programs. Compile *C* files as 32-bit using the `-m32` option. You also have to assemble `asm_io.asm` with a special define `-d ELF_TYPE` for this to work on Linux. Don't use `coff`. Commands like this should work:

```
nasm -f elf -d ELF_TYPE asm_io.asm
nasm -f elf first.asm 
gcc -m32 -c driver.c
gcc -m32 -o first driver.o first.o asm_io.o
```

If you are truly on 32-bit Linux you will be able to omit `-m32`

Answer (score 1):

I found that error is from asm_io.asm. You should have to modify asm_io.asm or check `define` lines.